# How to connect to oracle11g database?

Tags: sql, oracle

My oracle profile account password is expired and when I am trying to my oracle 11g using System and sysdba then Getting Error

```
ORA-28000: the account is locked
```

Can you guys help me to resolve this issue how I can login to my oracle 11g.

Comment: You need some help from your DBA

Comment: @Aleksej, not always :) It depends where and as which user you can login (UNIX/Linux)

Comment: Go to Run type cmd open the command prompt as a admin mode type below given command.

    sqlplus / as sysdba

enter old profile username and password it will ask for the new password if this solution does not work try below given command.

    C:\Users\Siry>sqlplus / as sysdba
    SQL> ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED;
    SQL> ALTER USER username IDENTIFIED BY "password";
    SQL> ALTER USER username ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
    Test by
    SQL> SELECT USERNAME,ACCOUNT_STATUS FROM DBA_USERS;

Comment: So the question is not how to connect to a database but how to unlock an account?

Answer (score 0):

You should login from the local machine, become oracle DBA user and use sqlplus on this way:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

and then unlock you profile with command:

```
alter user scott account unlock;
```

where **scott** is your user account

Comment: The OP said that the *account is locked*, so - why would you also change its password? `alter user scott account unlock` would do.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I did not find this command. Will update my answer :)